# Remove non-UTF8 characters from file contents

Tags: python, string, utf-8

I'm trying to read usernames from a database and if there are non-UTF-8 characters, it throws UnicodeDecodeError.

I'm unsure of what all the non-UTF8 characters are and I'm looking for a solution.

I want to keep special symbols, but just filter out the ones that aren't compatible with UTF-8. `³` and `™` (trademark), don't work with UTF-8, they're the only two I know of.

I still want to keep chinese symbols, arabic, etc. That's why I'm using UTF8.

Code:

```
def is_author_used(author):
        with open("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\authors.txt", 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            content = f.read().splitlines()
        if author in content:
            return True
        return False

    def set_author_used(author):
        with open("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\authors.txt", 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            f.write(author + '\r\n')
```

Comment: It seems that your files are simply not in UTF-8 format.

Only characters up to 0x7f are stored in "the usual way" in UTF-8. If you have a byte >= 0x80, it is part of a multibyte character.

Reading a file as UTF-8 which isn't indeed leads to errors.

Comment: the notepad/text document is in fact in UTF-8

Comment: What do you mean by "³ and  ™ (trademark), don't work with UTF-8"? Those are perfectly good Unicode characters and **all** Unicode characters can be represented as UTF-8.

Comment: I know, that's the thing. But for some reason it throws an error. My text document is UTF-8

Comment: Text file was made using notepad

Comment: Which operating system? If Windows, which Windows version? Are you using Python 2.x or 3.x? If you're using 2.x, I recommend switching to 3.x, especially if you deal with Unicode much (it's the default in 3.x, and it's very nice not having to worry about all the overhead). Is your Python file also UTF-8? Can you upload a text file that is implicated with the errors to Google Drive, DropBox, or such, and give us a link so we can analyze it? (You can strip out everything but the stuff that causes errors.)

Comment: @JosephJones Check the respective part in a hex editor and post the bytes and what decoded unicode you are expecting. Also, you can try using this tool, http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm, I'm pretty convinced that your file is just not UTF8.

Comment: You may have saved a text file in Notepad that had no non-ANSI characters in it as UTF-8 (in which case it wouldn't save it as UTF-8, in Windows in Notepad). If you added other characters later, they wouldn't be UTF-8, or, if they are non-ascii characters that are ANSI characters (e.g. ™), they wouldn't be enough to make it save as UTF-8. I highly recommend using Linux (or a different editor).

Comment: Or put a Chinese character somewhere in your text file before you save it as UTF-8 (and leave it there forever; if you remove it, the moment you save, it won't be UTF-8 anymore).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
with open('text.txt', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as f:
    content = f.read().splitlines()
```

Comment: I am not sure ignoring errors will solve the problem.

Comment: What happens when it finds an error? Does it stop the reading? Or does it just replace specific location in 'content' with an empty character?

Comment: `errors="ignore"` does exactly what it says, it filters non-UTF8 parts from the text.

Comment: Solving the problem (if this is what you want) without knowing the cause might have it's uses, but there could be other issues down the road, as well as issues right away that you do or do not notice, depending on the cause.

Comment: errors='ignore',  just ignore it , but did not remove all non utf8 characters. they are still there. how to remove it ?